# Finding the largest square that can be inscribed inside the astroid curve $x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=4$

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

Finding the largest square that can be inscribed inside the astroid curve $$x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=4$$

[image]

A square is described by four vertices. There will be one vertex of the square in each quadrant. I believe the vertex in the first quadrant will be where the astroid curve intersects the line $y=x$ and thus will have coordinates $(2\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2})$. Similarly, the vertices of the square in the other quadrants will be the horizontal/vertical/origin reflections of $(2\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2})$

Is this correct? How can I solve this question rigorously? Thanks!

Comment: A remark "down to earth" : asteroid $\to$ astroid.

Comment: I think you may be able to get larger square if diagonals of the square will coincide with axes.

Comment: That would be the smallest square.  If you rotate it, you can get a larger square.  If the corners have to be on the astroid, but the square inside the astroid, the limit will be when each side is tangent to the asteroid at the square's corner.

Comment: My square has side $16/\sqrt5$ which is smaller than the one mentioned by others here

Comment: If the tangent point is at $(8\cos^3\theta,8\sin^3\theta)$ then the tangent has slope $-\tan\theta$ and the square has side length $8\sin2\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably it is the tilted square with vertices $(\pm 4\sqrt{2},0)$, $(0,\pm4\sqrt{2})$ with area $64$. To prove this rigorously is probably quite difficult...

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6jy2kksmne

The following is not a rigorous proof, but is totally convincing, and could be turned into one.

Let $S$ be the (solid) square described above. Suppose for contradiction that $S'$ is a larger square. Then $S'\not\subset S$ so that a vertex $P$ of $S'$ lies outside of $S$ (because squares are *convex*). There are two tangent lines to the astroid passing through $P$ and the angle between them is less than 90 degrees. At this point, it is clear that $S'$ must have shorter sides than $S$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Neat answer!  I have an idea for a rigorous proof (Hint: find the largest disk inside the astroid )

Answer (score 4):

Let's show that the square in Joshua Tilley answer is the largest one.

If we have a square inside a region, then the inscribed disk of the square is also inside the region.

Now we may show that the inscribed disk $D$ of the above square $Q$ is the largest possible disk inside the astroid.  Indeed, consider a disk $D'$ inside the astroid. Where can its center lie? Can it be inside the square $Q$, and not its center? No, since it would be closer to one of its midpoints.  How about outside the square $Q$? Even worse.. So we found the unique largest disk inside, and the unique largest square inside.

$\bf{Added:}$ In the previous version of the answer I stated that for a region with a center of symmetry there exists a disk of largest radius inside the region with center at the center of symmetry. That is only true in general for convex regions, as @achille hui rightfully corrected me.  As a counterexample, consider the union of two equal disks.

However, the astroid has a certain property that makes the center special. What is it?  Join the two opposite vertices with line, intersecting at the center. In each region ( a quadrant) the complement of the astroid is convex.  This is the key.  Let these regions be $R_i$, $i=1,4$.  Now the distance from a point to $R$ is a convex function, since $R$  is convex. Moreover, the center has equal distances $d$ from all the $R_i$. We conclude that for any other point of the astroid the distance to  one of the $R_i$ ( that is, the distance to the boundary)  is $< d$.

Comment: @achille hui: yes, you are right, it can be two equal disks joined be a segment. Let me give it a correct proof. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for the "distance to convex $R$ is a convex function" part. that's genus. I don't get the part why center has equal distances to $R_i$ implies distance to one of $R_i$ is $< d$. I may figure that out after a good sleep.

Comment: Every point in the astroid is in one of the 4 triangles.  For each triangle, two points have distance $0$, and one has distance $d$.  So distance $< d$.  Now it is important that the $d$ is the same for all triangles. ...Thank you!

Comment: ahhh... it is that simple. how can I miss that? I really should go to sleep. thanks.